# Is "into the skin" in this sentence correct?

Tags: prepositions

Is "into the skin" in this sentence correct?

> Make sure you spread the ointment into the skin.

This sentence is from a vocabulary book that I am learning English with.

I thought "onto the skin" or "on the skin" is right instead of "into the skin".
If either is possible to use, then what is the difference between them?

Comment: Your first example sounds off - either you *spread it **on / onto** the skin* or you *massage it **into** the skin* if it's the kind of ointment that's applied like that.

Comment: *spread* or *put* **on/onto** the skin. *rub* or *work* or *massage* **into** the skin. If you imagine the actions I think you can understand the difference.

Comment: In other words, use *into* for a substance that will be absorbed by the skin; *on* or *onto* for a substance that will remain on the surface.  You'll need the appropriate verb in each instance.  *Spread* means cover a surface, so it's inapt with *into*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you for the reply, it was helpful. But what does "sounds off" mean in your reply? I am not a native English speaker and sorry about this question.

Comment: @user3169 Thank you for the reply. Now I understand the corresponding verb and preposition about this due to you.

Comment: @deadrat Thank you for the detailed, clear answer. It was so much helpful.

Comment: ***off*** [definition 6](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/off) *- away from what is considered normal, regular, standard, or the like*. A reasonable paraphrase for my first comment would be *...doesn't sound quite right [to me]*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example sentence

> Make sure you **spread** the ointment **into** the skin

is grammatically correct and understandable with the meaning

> **Apply** the ointment so that it **penetrates** the skin

however the phrasing may be found awkward by native speakers.  The awkwardness arises from the use of **spread**...**into**.

**Skin** is a surface which things are usually placed **on**, **over**, or **through** and sometimes **into**

> The wind **on** his skin made him feel cold
>   She poured water **over** her skin to wash it
>   The splinter pierced **through** his skin
>   The injection was made **into** the second layer of skin

Ointment can be applied **over** skin and then allowed to penetrate **into** the skin due to the latter's  **permeability**.

> Make sure **to spread** the ointment **over** your skin until it is **absorbed**

may convey the message you want with less awkwardness

Comment: Thank you for the explanation very much, Peter. I appreciate your answer.

Comment: If I may ask a bit more, do you mean the _example_ _sentence_ I asked about is wrong? That sentence is from a vocabulary learning book. When I first saw it, it felt awkward. And I got to know why it is awkward, thankfully due to your teaching. But I would like check whether or not the sentence is right, because I need to know if the book is trustworthy. Thank you. :)

Comment: The example question is fine and very understandable.  Usually instructions would read "Apply onto the skin, and allow to be absorbed" or "Spread until absorbed". I wouldn't say it's **wrong**, the grammar is correct, it's the semantics that's being discussed.  You'd also have to consider why the authors chose to use that particular phrasing, but it would't be what a native ear would expect for instructions.

Comment: Now I think I understand your words fully. I think you mean that in grammatical terms there is no errors in the sentence but there is a semantic problem. Is this what you mean correctly? Sorry to bother you. Thank you for the teaching.

Comment: Yes and the semantic concern is only a small one